# Ruby On Rails won't load assets from app/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting in de Ruby on Rails world (I'm the noobest noob), as far as I know, when I put .css and .js into the app/assets/stylesheets folder and javascripts folder, respectively, it should automatic load those files. But it just doesn't.

I've found this code line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

But it just renders the application.css into the HTML code.

Is there some setting I'm missing?

Ruby -v: 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

Rails -v: 4.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem wasn't Ruby, wasn't Rails... Wasn't even me (I think). The problem was Windows. I did exactly the same in the Mint partition and everything worked. Thanks you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

`stylesheet` and `javascript` folders are different asset types, so you should declare separately.

this is my `application.html.erg` layout.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Comment: Just like mine! I just made a new app out of the box, so, everything should be like default. But, should it load everything I put on those folders? That's what I understood from the tutorial.

Comment: Yes, you can verify with your `application.html.erg` and use `application.js`

Comment: @Jorge if you have these lines `*= require_tree . & *= require_self` in your stylesheet & js files then this will load all files in the directory otherwise not.